# Maximum values for line width (lwd) argument in RGL

Tags: r, rgl

I can't figure out why there is an apparent maximum limit to the `rgl` argument for an RGL function in R.  `segments3d()` cannot apparently support line widths over around 6-8, but this constraint doesn't seem to be documented.  The example demonstrates:

```
require(rgl)
x = rep(sample(1:10,50, rep=T), each=2)
y = rep(sample(1:10,50, rep=T), each=2)
z = rep(sample(1:10,50, rep=T), each=2)
z[(1:50)*2] = 0
d = data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)

segments3d(d, lwd=2)
segments3d(d, lwd=8)
segments3d(d, lwd=50)
```

Any view on why this is happening?

Comment: What did you have in mind with "cannot support" ? Seems to be working for me. At least I get the plots.

Comment: Do you see any difference between `lwd=8` and `lwd=50`?

Comment: Yes. I can upload pictures if you want to.

Comment: added pictures as an "answer". Just for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, just a demonstration of what I get.

```
segments3d(d, lwd=8)
```

[image: lwd8]

```
segments3d(d, lwd=50)
```

[image: lwd50]

Comment: That's very weird. I find in both Mac and Windows that I can't see any difference when I increase `lwd` above about 8.  Latest RGL version 0.94.1143.

Comment: could easily be an issue in the underlying OpenGL implementation(s)??

Comment: @geotheory I tested it on 2 linux machines (slackware and debian(ubuntu)) and it worked on both. Maybe you changed par3d() settings somehow? `par3d(r3dDefaults)` might be worth a try? (or something similar, like `par3d(scale=c(1,1,1))`.

Comment: Thanks for testing and the suggestions.  The par options have no effect.  Oh well :)